# Why does `justify-content: stretch` require `flex-grow` to make input elements expand

Tags: css, flexbox

In the following snippet, where I am making response form, where labels are above on mobile, and to left with desktop. The elements with a `.field` class have `justify-content: stretch`, which should make the items expand to fit the available space.

However I find that the `<input>` elements do not expand. I have to add `flex-grow: 1` to it in order to make it expand to fill the available width.

This shows I don't understand what `stretch` is doing. Why is the `flex-grow` required.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content):

> justify-content: stretch;       /* Distribute items evenly
> Stretch 'auto'-sized items to fit
> the container */

And you can see below the `.input` elements have `width: auto`.

UPDATE: I added the `div.not-needed` elements below to show a flew child can be a flex parent to and it does not make the difference. This way I separated the two layers of flex parents.

Later on in the MDN link it says:

> Note: stretch is not supported by flexible boxes (flexbox).

So the `stretch` value is only valid for `grid` for now I think, and not flexbox.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.label {
    width: 100px;
}

.input {
   width: auto;   
   flex-grow: 1;
}

.field {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="not-needed">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="ID_FIELD_1" class="label">Label 1</label>
            <input  id="ID_FIELD_1" class="input" type="text" name="field_1" value="Value 1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="not-needed">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="ID_FIELD_2" class="label">Label 2</label>
            <input  id="ID_FIELD_2" class="input" type="text" name="field_2" value="Value 2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="not-needed">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="ID_FIELD_3" class="label">Label 3</label>
            <input  id="ID_FIELD_3" class="input" type="text" name="field_3" value="Value 3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `stretch` doesn't apply to flexbox (see [this explaination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#stretch)) so, in reality, the browser is ignoring that property and `flex-grow` is doing all the work itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `justify-content` property has to be applied to flex containers and not to it's items.
Even then it just defines how the space **between** and **around** content items is distributed (see CSS [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)).

For filling the available space, the item element (your `input`) has to grow (e.g. `flex-grow: 1`) or it's width to be set (e.g. `width: 100%`).

Comment: `.field` is a flex container, which contains the `justify-content: stretch`